# Как расставить знаки препинания в этом предложении? (2)

Tags: синтаксис, запятые

Мы знаем как вы любите сладкое и в этот солнечный день предлагаем вам попробовать — какой десерт вам больше всего подходит.

Есть ли тут запятые и тире или нет?

Comment: @shampar, Автор поставил знак вопроса в конце своего предложения, а Вы его убрали.... Разве мы вправе оригинал менять?

Comment: Был  выбор — исправить опечатку, или признать ошибкой и минусовать. Я сегодня за мир и дружбу.

Comment: Если это предложение не из какого-то произведения, я бы посоветовала  заменить слово "попробовать" на "определить" или "выяснить".

Answer (score 1):

**Мы знаем, как вы любите сладкое, и в этот солнечный день предлагаем вам попробовать, какой десерт вам больше всего подходит.**

"Как вы любите сладкое" и "какой десерт вам больше всего подходит" — придаточные предложения (с союзными словами), они выделяются запятыми. Предложение повествовательное, в конце ставится точка.

Answer (score 1):

Да, это сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточными изъяснительными.